# error con SpringBoot e Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot

estoy realizando una api de practica y estan son mis clases.
Las entidades y la relaciones se guardan correctamente si hago con postman.
La api tambien trabaja con JWT, eso también funciona correctamente ya que me genera el token de acceso normal.

El promblema que tengo es que al querer traer todos los topicos desde la base de datos con el metodo get, me saltan 4 errores en consola.

1- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

2- java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

3- org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied

4- jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed.

Acabe recalcar que el endpoint para traer los topicos esta publico, no tiene restricción alguna.

Esta mi entidad usuario

@Table(name="usuario", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username","email"})})
@Entity
public class Usuario implements UserDetails {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id_usuario;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private String curso;
private String username;
private String password;
private String email;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role rol;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "usu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Topico> lista_topicos;


@OneToMany (mappedBy = "usu_respuesta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Respuesta> lista_respuestas;
```

}

La entidad Topico.

```
 @Entity
 public class Topico {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id_topico;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String titulo;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String mensaje;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fecha_creacion;
@Convert(converter = TrueFalseConverter.class)
private boolean estado;

@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "usu_id")
private Usuario usu;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Respuesta> lista_respuesta;
```

}

y la entidad Respuesta

```
@Entity
public class Respuesta {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id_respuesta;
private String texto_respuesta;

@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name = "topico_id")
private Topico topic;

@ManyToOne
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private Usuario usu_respuesta;
```

}

Comment: El error está en la lógica, no en las entidades. Deberías poner el código del controlador y del servicio, si tienes

Comment: Que controlador y servicio necesitas ver? puedo pasarlo

Comment: En algún sitio parece que estás intentando responder a una request dos veces, lo que causa el primer error. Si añadieras el stack trace, sería más fácil verlo

Comment: @PabloLozano por lo que veo en el primer erro me salta que hay algo esta clase.
at com.foroalura.ChallengeApiRest.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:36) ~[classes/:na]

No puedo copiar todo el error, porque no me dan los caracteres para hacerlo.

Aunque esa clase solo se encarga de validar el token, obtener el usuario.